# Symfony - Object of class TemplateReference could not be converted to int

Tags: php, symfony, templating

I've been working on a Symfony CRM for some time now but need to add more functionality for the client. Basically this is a new section to be able to add products to a specific customer based on entry of a product ID.

The functionality is not in place yet, but for some reason after I created an entity called OrderProductsTemp I got the following notice on the page I'd added:

> Object of class
>   Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Templating\TemplateReference could not
>   be converted to int

Referring to a line in the `FilesystemLoader.php` file within the Symfony Templating directory structure. The line it claims to have an error with is:

```
return filemtime((string) $storage) < $time;
```

Which I guess is what's loading in each template - but I cannot tell which one is casuing the issue. I did a print on $storage within the loop to see if I could detect something and all I got was:

> storage:
>   /var/www/vhosts/crm.mysite.com/app/Resources/views/default/index.html.twig
>   storage:
>   /var/www/vhosts/crm.mysite.com/app/Resources/views/default/index.html.twig
>   storage:
>   /var/www/vhosts/crm.mysite.com/app/Resources/views/default/index.html.twig
>   storage:
>   /var/www/vhosts/crm.mysite.com/app/Resources/views/default/index.html.twig
>   storage:
>   /var/www/vhosts/crm.mysite.com/app/Resources/views/default/index.html.twig
>   storage:
>   /var/www/vhosts/crm.mysite.com/app/Resources/views/default/index.html.twig

"mysite" being the client's web address of course.

This notice appears now on every page of the CRM and I cannot understand what is causing this - I've deleted the new entity I created and undone (to the best of my memory) everything I did in the last half hour since when it was OK but still the error persists.

Anyone have any ideas? I've already searched SO for a possible solution but nothing really jumps out at me.

EDIT - code that generates the add order page:

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $order_repo = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Oc49Order');
        $customer_repo = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Oc49Customer');
        $customer = $customer_repo->findOneBy(array('id' => $request->get('customer_id')));
        $add_products = new Oc49Product();
        $add_products_form = $this->createForm(new AddProductsType(), $add_products);

        if ($request->getMethod() == 'POST') {
            $add_products_form->handleRequest($request);

            if ($add_products_form->isValid()) {
                $add_products->setCustomerId($request->get('customer_id'));
                $add_products->setDateAdded(new \DateTime());
                $em->persist($add_products);
                $em->flush();

                return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('app_customer_order_add', array('customer_id' => $request->get('customer_id'), 'recommended' => 'added')));
            }
        }

        $returnArray['groups'] = $this->getGroupList();
        $returnArray['title'] = "Add Customer Order";
        $returnArray['species_list'] = $this->getSpeciesList();
        $returnArray['stores'] = $this->getStoreList();
        $returnArray['add_products_form'] = $add_products_form->createView();
        $returnArray['customer'] = $customer;

        return $this->render('AppBundle:forms:customerorderform.html.twig', $returnArray);
```

Comment: `..new section to be able to add products to a specific customer based on entry of a product ID` , what is relevant related code?

Comment: Added it to the question